# jquery animate resize to left rather than to the right on Chrome/IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have four corners that when one is clicked, it expands to fill the screen from whatever corner it belongs to to the opposite corner. I've looked at a lot of the answers, and most either suggest changing margins, which severely messes up my layout, or animating the left edge, like so

```
$("#topRightBG").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
        "zIndex": 20,
        "cursor": "default"
    }).stop(false, true).animate({
        "height": outUp,
        "width": outSide,
        "left": 0
    }, {
        duration: speed_out,
        easing: style_out
    });
});
```

The only problem is, the movement to the left doesn't animate, it just jumps, as I demonstrate [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XfeGN/6/).

I feel like changing the left edge is what I want to do, but I'm not sure how to get it to work properly. Can anyone help?

**Realized it works in Firefox at least, but not Chrome and IE.**

Comment: hope this could help http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/65QsU/

Comment: Same as a previous answer that was apparently deleted....uses margins which I'd said would require a total rewrite of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that all I need to do is separately animate the movement to the left.

```
$("#topRightBG").click (function () {
    $(this).css({
        "zIndex": 20,
        "cursor": "default"
    }).stop(false, true).animate({
        "height": outUp,
        "width": outSide
    }, {
        duration: speed_out,
        easing: style_out
    }).animate({
        "left": 0
    }, {
        duration: speed_out,
        easing: style_out
    });
});
```